# SSD m.2 NVMe not being recognized by Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, dell-inspiron, nvme

I bought an [XPG 8200 pro](https://www.xpg.com/en/feature/583/) 512GB NVMe SSD to use as my main drive in my [Dell Inspiron 5480 14](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-14-5480-laptop/overview)". [Dell's manual](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-14-5480-laptop_setup-guide_en-us.pdf) specifies it supports Ubuntu, and in the Storage section says the M.2 slot will accept a 2230/2280 solid-state drive PCIe Gen3 x4 NVMe drive.

I tried to install Debian and Arch based systems, but none of them even recognized the SSD as a device by `inxi` or `lshw`; `fdisk` and `lsblk` just return my HDD and USB installation drives.

I've already tried to:

- Change the SATA settings to Disabled, AHCI and Raid On;
- Turn secure boot on and off;
- Wipe the disk;
- Update the BIOS;
- And some other things that I just don't remember.

I actually plan to install MX Linux.

How may I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Please shut down your PC, power back up, and enter your BIOS/Settings. A) Does the NVMe drive appear there? If it does not show up there, Linux will never see it.... B) Is Fast Boot off? C) Is Secure Boot still off? D) Have you contacted Dell Support?  What did they say? E) Have you contacted ADATA support https://www.adata.com/global/ss/fixonline/  and what did they say? Please click [edit] and add answers to A-E to expand your question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].